# Spring Validator + Ajax showing bindingResultErrors

Tags: ajax, spring, validation, jsp, model-view-controller

I would like to call a server - side validation before submitting the form and show all the errors on fields: i click submit button, if validation failed, i stay at the same page and send to my form an errors with every field

I have:

**My form:**

```
<form:form  action="${action}" method="POST" class="ajaxForm" id="myForm" modelAttribute="order" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type ="hidden" name="id" value="${order.id}"/>
   
   <form:input type="text" id="number" path="number" class="form-control"
               value="${order.number}" />
   
        <form:errors path="number" class="control-label" />
//etc
<spring:bind path="number">
</spring:bind>
</form:form>
```

**js**

```
  $("#myForm").submit(function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#myForm").ajaxSubmit({url: '/editOrder', type: 'post'})

        });
```

**my controller method**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/editOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editEmployeeTripOrder(HttpServletRequest request, 
@Valid @ModelAttribute("order") Order order,
                                        BindingResult bindingResult,
                                        ModelMap modelMap) {
 
try {
       
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     //stay here and show the errors     
return bindingResult.getAllErrors();
     }

return "success";//view - jsp page



} catch (Exception e) {
  return "error";//jsp-page
}
```

Can't understand how to perform this to use view's name returning value and returning the errors at the same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using ajax call and httpErrorCode